# Specifying the path to a hdfs directory within a python script on anaconda

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I'm using anaconda on VM and I have a line that's supposed to find a file in hdfs, but when I run the code

```
/path-to-hdfs/
```

it becomes

```
file/upload/project/envs/default/path-to-hdfs
```

It's basically trying to find the document within anaconda.

How can I change it so that it doesn't change my link

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `hdfs://` prefix, however Python doesn't natively read from HDFS